# what is the proper way of encrypting the secret key of AES

Tags: encryption, password-encryption

I am using following library to do client side encryption
http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/

It works fine, the user defines a password and a key, and I encrypt everything on client side before pushing it to the server.

I want to make the user interaction easier, currently it's tedious for the user to both remember the secret key and the password, I would like to encrypt the secret key with the user defined password and concatenate it to the cipher text. What is a good approach to this?

What is a good way of encrypting the secret key using the user defined password, concatenating it with the cipher text?

Comment: Broadly speaking, you use "key stretching" to turn the password into a secret key and then use that to encrypt the saved key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use key stretching as chrylis indicates. In that case you can use PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2 to generate a key from the password. You'd need to configure the work factor and save a salt with the ciphertext.

After you generate a key in such a way you can wrap (encrypt) another random data key with it. You could also use it directly or together with a KBKDF such as HKDF to generate a data key.

Comment: I am fairly new to this, so please excuse my ignorance. Is PBKDF2 considered key stretching? Currently I am taking the user defined password, then I generate a random salt and then I run Pbkdf2 1000 x on the user defined password to generate a 256 bit  secret key. My question is, how do I securely concat the secret key with my cipher text and then decrypt it later to decrypt the secret message? I am more or less doing exacly what is done here, I just want to know a good approach to eliminate the need to remember the 256 secret key. bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/demo/

Comment: Why do you want to conceal the secret key? You only need to regenerate it by running PBKDF2 again. Note that 1000 iterations is considered on the very low end, 50K would be better. Or you can use a very secure pass phrase of course.

Comment: Will PBKDF2 regenerate exact same key? I was under the impression it has some randomness that will generate a different key. Is it safe to use teh same password, salt and IV for the actual cipher text as I am for the secret key? I keep on hearing, don't use the same IV more than once.

Comment: Given the same salt it will generate the same key. You should indeed use a ramdom IV if unsure. You can store salt and IV with the ciphertext...